# How should i cast structure of char pointer array into array of array of char?

Tags: c

```
struct command
{
    char *abc[1000];
};
```

One of the variable is defined in a structure. This char pointer array contains the value after reading the value from file. For example `{123,121}`.
Now I want to cast these value in array of array of char, something like this:

```
    char a1[][1000]= s1->abc[j];
```

I am not sure about the syntax... So how should I cast these values in array `abc` in `a1`.

Comment: It does not take meaningful values by substituting even cast.

Comment: Your description is vague and code you have posted makes no sense at all. Please provide *short* program that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have an array of 1000 `char*`, that might have different length (in your example, length is 2). And `s1` type is `struct command`.

Then I think you meant:

```
char a1[1000][] = s1->abc;
```

Or:

```
char a1[] = s1->abc[j];
```

But I am not sure why you would want to do that instead of:

```
char * a1[1000] = s1->abc;
```

Or

```
char ** a1 = s1->abc
```

Be careful with indexes though...